# Samba domain controller: remove 1 Windows client

Tags: linux, samba, domain, opensuse

my domain is controlled by a Samba domain controller running on openSUSE 11.3.
It manages other openSUSE boxes and some Windows 7 boxes.

Now one harddisk of a Windows 7 computer crashed and I had to reinstall.
I wasn't able to get the computer name ("Win26") of the broken PC out of the domain and so I couldn't add the reinstalled "Win26" to the domain again.

So how can I remove the entry of the old "Win26" computer out of the domain controller, so that I can add the new "Win26" to the domain again?
Is it one configuration file I have to edit and restart Samba? Which file would this be?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards,

KB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "Win26$" user account from the system. The easiest way to do this is probably by running`pdbedit -x -m Win26` on the server machine.

Comment: Thank you! I theory this was what I wanted. But I am still not able to add my Windows PC to the domain. I also tried `/etc/init.d/smb restart` after `pdbedit -x -m Win26`. Am I missing some other command?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps ``pdbedit -x Win26\$`` ?

Comment: I think your first proposal was correct, because with `pdbedit -x Win26\$` it gives me _"user Win26$ does not exist in the passdb"_.

Answer (score 2):

After `pdbedit -x -m Win26` you have to run `userdel Win26\$` (escape the $ sign) to remove machine linux user account.

Comment: Yes, userdel is needed: `m=Win26; pdbedit -x -m $m; userdel $m\$`